# CrystalReports Viewer object is not available

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm creating a local application in C# with Crystal Reports, in the design part is all ok, but when I want to use the tool Crystal Reports Viewer it is not available in the toolbox window, how I can turn it available to use it?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I resolved it, the problem was about de Framework version, it was selected .NET Framework 4 client Profile, I switched to .NET Framework 4 and the object turn available :)

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports Viewer is a stand-alone application to let the user see the Crystal Report without having to purchase a license. It is available @

http://www.businessobjects.com/forms/crystalreports/viewer/

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you change your project properties to .NET Framework 4.

Comment: the comment from the OP indicates they already figured that out.